# Making grid items stick together on larger screens

Tags: html, css, svelte

I have a grid container which contains a side navigation and a main content area. The layout itself works well at the default zoom or on a reasonably small screen (testing with a 15").

[Default Zoom on 15"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgcoP.png)

However, if the page is either zoomed out or rendered on a larger screen the grid items spread out to consume the available space. I've tried numerous solutions such as the `justify-content: center` property but nothing seems to make the columns stick to the main content.

[Maximally zoomed out on a 15"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEHgX.png)

The code is available for inspection [here](https://github.com/jamesb93/phd-sapper) and the CSS in question is [here](https://github.com/jamesb93/phd-sapper/blob/master/src/routes/_layout.svelte). The two main elements, `<main>` and a svelte component for the side nav `<StaticNav />` sit inside the `<div>` with the CSS class named `.wrapper` which uses `display: grid`.

How can I make it so that no matter the screen size the side nav will stick next to the main content?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you want to make your content center whatever the screen size is. Then try this,

body {max-width: 70%; justify-content: center}

You can use this css media queries for specific screen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the layout as you put it there, you *could* do the following:

```css
.wrapper {
   grid-template-columns: max-content min(63ch, 50%) 1fr;
}
```

With the `max-content` your sidebar would automatically adjust to the maximum lenght of the items in it, only taking as much place as required, effectively making the main content 'stick' to it on the left.

To get everything more centered you could add another `1fr` at the beginning as well

```css
.wrapper {
   grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content min(63ch, 50%) 1fr;
}
```

But in that case you have to be aware that you need to use either grid-areas or throw in an empty element to take the first column of your grid.